# how to read multiple json values?

Tags: python, json

I have the following json output:

```
{
  "status" : "success",
  "data" : {
    "class" : "4A",
    "students" : [
      {
        "name" : "Peter",
        "lastname" : "Henderson",
        "grades" : [
          {
            "subject" : "math",
            "score" : "A"
          },
          { 
            "subject" : "english",
            "score" : "B"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name" : "Nick",
        "lastname" : "Simons",
        "grades" : [
          {
            "subject" : "math",
            "score" : "B"
          },
          {
            "subject" : "english",
            "score" : "C"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I can not find out how i print all grades for every student.

I assume you need a for loop to loop throug all the students and then a second for loop to check all their grades, but i cannot find the syntax for this in python.

Hopefully someone knows how to fix this, thanks for you time already!

Comment: Fix what? I see a requirement here, not an attempt at solving the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the following code, `response` being your `json`:

```
data = response['data']['students']

for student in data:
    print('{} {}:'.format(student['name'], student['lastname']))
    for grade in student['grades']:
        print('\t{} - {}'.format(grade['subject'], grade['score']))
```

This is what you'd get:

```
Peter Henderson:
        math - A
        english - B
Nick Simons:
        math - B
        english - C
```